# Bell's theorem and fluid-mechanical experiments using droplets: are local hidden-variable theories possible after all?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, bells-inequality, non-locality

Recent fluid-mechanical experiments by the groups of Couder in Paris and Bush at MIT, mimic a surprisingly wide range of quantum effects. The essential ingredient of these fluid-mechanical systems is a background or pilot-wave that guides the droplets.

Now, surprisingly, a simple analysis of a Bell-type experiment shows that, in the presence of a background field, one of the premises of the Bell inequality, namely measurement independence (MI), is violated. See the paper ["No-Go Theorems Face Background-Based Theories for Quantum Mechanics"](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10701-015-9973-7) (available [on arxiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/1406.0901)). Therefore such classical droplet experiments could violate a Bell inequality. More importantly, if this analysis is correct, background-based hidden-variable theories are admissible, even if they are local (in the sense of ‘involving only (sub)luminal interactions’) and even if they are compatible with free will.

My question: to me the analysis seems fully sound, but maybe there is still an unphysical hypothesis that slipped in ?

Comment: Your link is broken. One can mimic quantum effects in a classical computer, be it analog or digital, this one just happens to be analog. Absolutely nothing stops you from simulating superluminal effects, by the way, so I am not sure where you are going ontologically. A simulation can always do "physics as usual", "physics 2.0" and, if you want it can also do "no physics at all".

Comment: Could you update the link, please, and preferably give a citation so that link-rot is not a problem? I would really like to look at the paper! Thanks!

Comment: @CuriousOne. Could be: http://arxiv.org/abs/1406.0901

Comment: @CuriousOne. It looks like you can win $1000 (from the author himself) if you find a flaw in the math of this paper. See  http://www.minkowskiinstitute.org/Vervoort-r1.html ...

Comment: @StéphaneRollandin: He will certainly not lose that money to me. At least the paper is somewhat thought provoking. I am already happy with that.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments ! Here is maybe a better link: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10701-015-9973-7. The full reference is: “No-go theorems face background-based theories for quantum mechanics” (2016a), Foundations of Physics, Volume 46, Issue 4, pp 458-472. If anyone can go through the straightforward math and give comments, would be great.

Comment: I thought Steve Gull showed with his computer network that a quantum correlations are different to quantum correlations? The same idea is reintroduced in this paper: http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0301059v2
Not sure how it relates to this question and the linked paper.

Comment: Dear LouisV: Are you in any way associated with the author of the link? For your information, Physics.SE has a [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/582/2451) that it is OK to cite oneself, but it should be stated clearly and explicitly in the answer itself, not in attached links.

Answer (score 4):

For the sake of argument, I will assume that all of the calculations of the authors are correct- I don't see any obvious reason that they cannot be.

A few notes:

1. As the authors note, the measurements independence criterion of the Bell Inequality is a well-known assumption. So pointing it out, by itself, is not an interesting contribution. What one could hope is that analysis of these droplet experiments leads to a plausible model for how this assumption could be violated.
2. The authors show that suitable background correllations could in principle lead to a Bell violation in a droplet experiment, but they do not specify what observable would actually exhibit these correllations. It is presumably the case that such an observable would have to be 'fine-tuned,' in the sense that you would have to work to figure out how to make a measurement that is suitably affected by the background. There is a good reason they do not propose a specific way of doing this- they do not know one, and it may well be that any suitable observable would be too complex a measurement to be practical.
3. In general, their model predicts significant deviations from quantum mechanics. As they note, they predict a Bell violation that depends on how fast one chooses the measurements, and as I mentioned it should depend on the observable chosen as well. Of course, one could imagine that we have picked just the wrong frequency range and observables in all of our Bell experiments to see this disagreement.
4. In [a recent claim](http://arxiv.org/abs/1511.03189) of a loophole free Bell test, the random choice of measurement comes from both physical processes that are believed to be random, and also from streams of bits that are derived from things like files of various movies and television shows. So a model of Bell's inequality that violated background independence in this case would have to plausibly explain how all these things could be correlated, or how there could be some exploitable glitch in how these random bits are actually implemented as measurement settings. Needless to say, I have not seen such a model yet.

Comment: On your notes: 1,2. The topic of the article is not really to argue that a Bell inequality can be violated in droplet experiments (this is just a corollary), but to show that background-based hidden-variable theories for QM are admissible. 4. Thanks for the ref. Another recent ‘loophole-free’ experiment is done by the Zeilinger group. However, if a background field exists (vacuum fluctuations, the ether, or a fancy dark field), then one cannot close the freedom-of-choice loophole: see details in http://arxiv.org/abs/1602.01859. If correct, the article stands !

Comment: One does not necessarily need such a fancy background field- one point I have heard made (by one of the authors of the paper I linked to) is that all the electronics in the experiment are of course hooked up to the same power grid, and one could in principle imagine some weird electrical surge that is just right to trick us. My personal feeling is that until I see a plausible physical model for such 'conspiracies,' I do not find them very interesting. But, I certainly freely admit that they exist as a logical possibility.

Comment: To stress @Rococo argument : To explain the experiment reported in arXiv:1511.03186, such a background field should direct the bits of a MPEG4(?) file encoding the *Back to the future* movie. Which means that such a fully deterministic theory implies specific correlations between the mind of Robert Zemeckis in 1985 and the polarization measurement of some photons in 2016 : something probably impossible to disprove from physics, but still quite implausible.

Comment: oil drop experiments are not claiming to violate bells's inequality, as they have not yet been able to get to an analogue of entanglement. They argue thought that a non local fluid (a a fully correlated one could result in entanglement, but that is still speculative.

Answer (score 0):

In 2022 they (K Papatryfonos, L Vervoort, A Nachbin, M Labousse, JWM Bush) made experiment claiming CHSH violation: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2208.08940 - using pair of droplets, each being able to choose one of two cavities:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This paper is wrong at the most basic level, without needing to go into the details that Rococo's answer does.

Bell's assumptions were very general: his argument only needs the measurement outcomes to be $A(\mathbf a, λ)$ and $B(\mathbf b, λ)$ where $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$ are the chosen measurement angles, $λ$ is an arbitrary collection of hidden variables, and $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary functions. You may in particular take $λ$ to be a pilot wave or background field or something of that sort. The idea that quantum behavior might be explained by a pilot wave was as old as quantum mechanics, and ruling out models of that sort was the main aim of Bell's paper, as far as I know.

Vervoort suggests in his abstract that Bell (and apparently everyone else since 1964) overlooked the possibility of what he calls "local background-based" theories. I have no idea what he thinks Bell's paper is about.

His argument that measurement independence is violated in background-based theories (section 3) is simply that there is bidirectional interaction between $\mathbf a$ and the background which causes them to become correlated. This argument would demolish Bell's argument in complete generality if it worked. It makes no assumptions related to fluid droplets or the experiments of Couder et al, so I'm not sure why he mentioned those. The problem with the argument is that Bell's $\mathbf a$ is the measurement that the experimenter chooses and writes down in their log book, not the measurement that actually happens. If the background messes with the measurement device and changes the angle before the actual measurement takes place, you can encode that interaction into the definition of $A$, and nothing about Bell's argument changes.