Wave interference and fluid dynamics question
I'm curious to find an answer to this question:
In the college canteen I would often slide my Styrofoam cup of milky coffee across the melamine table top. (unlike paper or plastic, Styrofoam is a little bit sticky). This caused vibration in the liquid and some nice interference patterns on the coffee's surface. Sometimes little standing waves of hill-like bumps, and sometimes, if you get the slide-speed just right, some of these 'bumps' appear to pinch off and become little independent balls of coffee that seem to slide or roll around the surface!.
But I was never able to determine whether they really were little independent balls of coffee, holding their spherical shape by their own surface tension, or whether they were merely the result of wave-interference, analogous to the way the way a ripple merely "appears" to move across the surface of a pond when really its just bits of water locally moving up and down.
I thought of doing an experiment, shooting a bit of blue ink from a syringe across the path of a coffee-ball, if the ball retains it's coffee color as it crosses the line of blue ink, then it's an independent ball, if it momentarily turns blue while crossing the line of blue ink, subsequently regaining it's coffee color, then its a wave-interference phenomenon.
Which is it, an independent "ball" or a "moving interference pattern"? and how can you be sure?
Either way though it looks pretty cool! The principle involved might make a poetic analogy to make some point or other about wave-particle interaction or particles as an excitation of a field.

See https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.94.177801 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nmC0ygr08tE

Also see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/250970/bells-theorem-and-fluid-mechanical-experiments-using-droplets-are-local-hidden

Experimentally a better cell phone can most like take a sufficiently high resolution photo to answer the question. Give it a try. Cool anecdote: A student in my senior high school class asked me to modify a camera flash for him to study phenomena like this. His parents had a good 35mm film camera and he knew how to take photographs. I knew how to trigger a flash with a photo sensor and a delay circuit. I made a little circuit for him, he happily took it home and a couple weeks later he showed us stunning photographs of falling droplets and droplets bouncing off a water surface.
